# Recreating a table as a list

Tags: enumerate, indentation, labels, enumitem

I'm trying to recreate a table I've made as a list, because it is easier to customize and is consistent over the whole document. But I can't get the label indentation right. I can't figure out what `labelindent`, `labelwidth`, `labelsep − itemindent`, `itemindent` and `leftmagin` each do. I also doon't know whether to use `descritption`, `itemize` or `enumerate` as they all allow custom labels.

The labels should look like in the table, where they are all aligned to the left margin. The bold text and the next line should have the same indentation, regardless of label width. And the space between the label and the bold text should be bigger.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right= 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}r@{}c@{}lX}
    03/2020 & \ -- \ & heute & \textbf{Company -- Bachelorarbeit} \\
    & & & Test und Evaluierung von Designkriterien für lasergeschmolzene Titanteile im SLM-Prozess unter Verwendung von Heitzelementen \\[10pt]
    08/2018 & -- & 01/2019 & \textbf{Company -- Praktikumssemester} \\ 
    & & & Abteilung Entwicklungs / Standardisierung \\[10pt]
    07/2017 & -- & 08/2017 & \textbf{Company -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    & & & Instandhaltung Mechanik \\[10pt]
    07/2016 & -- & 08/2016 & \textbf{Company -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    & & & Ausbildungszentrum / Montage Antrieb \\
\end{tabularx}

\begin{enumerate}[widest=08/2018 -- 01/2019, leftmargin= 2cm]
    \item[03/2020 -- heute] \textbf{Company -- Bachelorarbeit} \\
    Test und Evaluierung von Designkriterien für lasergeschmolzene Titanteile im SLM-Prozess unter Verwendung von Heitzelementen
    \item[08/2018 -- 01/2019] \textbf{Company -- Praktikumssemester} \\
    Abteilung Entwicklungs / Standardisierung
    \item[07/2017 -- 08/2017] \textbf{Company -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    Instandhaltung Mechanik
    \item[07/2016 -- 08/2016] \textbf{Company -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    Ausbildungszentrum / Montage Antrieb
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably, it could be easier to replace the tabular lines by item lines, using a regular expression. From within Emacs the command  (query-replace-regexp "^[ ]*\\([0-9/]+\\)\\ *&[ \\-]+&\\([^&]*\\)&\\([^&]+\\)&[ ]+&[ ]+&\\([^\\]+\\).*" "\\\\item[\\1 -- \\2 ] \\3 \\4" nil nil nil nil nil) does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the following is closer to the desired output: (Red lines indicate the margins) To increase the distance between the first and the secind column can be adjusted using `labelsep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right= 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}r@{}c@{}lX}
    03/2020 & \ -- \ & heute & \textbf{FIT AG -- Bachelorarbeit} \\
    & & & Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR \\[10pt]
    08/2018 & -- & 01/2019 & \textbf{Maschinenbau Silberhorn GmbH -- Praktikumssemester} \\ 
    & & & Abteilung Entwicklungs / Standardisierung \\[10pt]
    07/2017 & -- & 08/2017 & \textbf{Maschinenfabrik Reinhausen -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    & & & Instandhaltung Mechanik \\[10pt]
    07/2016 & -- & 08/2016 & \textbf{Maschinenfabrik Reinhausen -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    & & & Ausbildungszentrum / Montage Antrieb \\
\end{tabularx}

\begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{08/2018 -- 01/2019},
                    labelsep=20pt,
                    leftmargin =\labelwidth+\labelsep,
                    font=\normalfont]
    \item[03/2020 -- heute] \textbf{FIT AG -- Bachelorarbeit} \\
    Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR
    \item[08/2018 -- 01/2019] \textbf{Maschinenbau Silberhorn GmbH -- Praktikumssemester} \\
    Abteilung Entwicklungs / Standardisierung
    \item[07/2017 -- 08/2017] \textbf{Maschinenfabrik Reinhausen -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    Instandhaltung Mechanik
    \item[07/2016 -- 08/2016] \textbf{Maschinenfabrik Reinhausen -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    Ausbildungszentrum / Montage Antrieb
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Among others, You can use the `hang` package for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hang,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{labeledlist}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} 
\item[Whatever]       {\bfseries \lipsum[1][3]}\par \lipsum[1][4-9]. 
\item[One more label] {\bfseries \lipsum[2][5]}\par \lipsum[1][4-9]. 
\end{labeledlist}
\end{document}
```